# How to Resolve Linq to SQL ChangeConflictException When Record Has Been Removed From Database

Tags: c#, winforms, linq-to-sql

I am currently trying to resolve an issue where our application occassionally throws a `ChangeConflictException` with the following error message: `Unable to refresh the specified object.  The object no longer exists in the database.`

I can reproduce this error message by performing the following steps.  First, we load a form that displays the details of a service work order.  The WorkOrder object associated with this form has many associations (e.g. customer, jobs, job items, addresses, etc...).  The data context stays open until the form is closed.  Next, if one of the associations is deleted while this form is loaded a ChangeConflictException will result when the user attempts to save the WorkOrder associated with the form because the session has a object in the cache with an id that no longer exists in the database.

I understand why we are getting the exception but, I'd like to know what the best practice is for handling this type of scenario.  Also, is there a way that I can identify which object no longer exists in the database?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue In Asp.net/vb.net

```
Dim db As New MyDataContext
MyObject.Detach()
db.MyTable.Attach(MyObject)
db.Refresh(RefreshMode.KeepCurrentValues, MyObject)'Error Happens Here
db.SubmitChanges()
```

Solution that helped me

```
Dim db As New MyDataContext
MyObject.Detach()
db.MyTable.Attach(MyObject)
 'Commented Out the Line
db.SubmitChanges()
```

The Refresh() method doesn't retrieve new records from the database.

I'm not entirely sure why that is - just one of those choices that the Linq to SQL product team made (presumably with good reasons). It could have something to do with the fact that the refresh method

is primarily designed for optimistic concurrency conflict resolution 1
To get the newly entered records you will need to either:

Reissue a new query on the same DataContext
Create a new instance of your DataContext
Which option you go with depends on context (no pun intended). Things to bear in mind are the intended Unit of Work nature of the Linq to SQL DataContext and the intended short life span of the Datacontext.

Hope It Helps